# How to create a direct link to an account to log in directly without username and password using auth0

Tags: auth0

I want to create a *direct link* .so that , I could give it to my customer to log in without username and password.

I tried the `/users/{user_id}/impersonate` but it last for a short amount of time. I want permanent link!

Comment: or can I create a link embedded with username and password ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Impersonate. As you're saying, it's for a short amount of time.

You could create tickets in your DB that never expire. Then, you have an endpoint like `/automatic-login/[ticketId]` that receives a TicketID which must be on your DB. If the TicketId is on your DB; you call at that precise moment to the Impersonate API from Auth0, get the link back and then send a redirect to the USER to that impersonate endpoint.

That way, you're using Impersonation in that precise moment, so it will work.

Makes sense?

Comment: yeah I got what you , the problem now that when I use the auth0 api to generate an impersonate link , it won't work , it generates a link but it doesn't work , it keeps getting me an error.                                              error cannot GET /user/....

Comment: Hmm  that's weird. Can you connect to chat.auth0.com and talk to somebody there? It'll be easier to help you than in here :).